# iam learning REACTJS but i had an error if anyone can help me

Tags: reactjs

This is the error :
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Code :

```
import React from 'react'
import Product from './Product'
import vschoolProducts from './vschoolProducts'

function App() {

        const productComponenets = vschoolProducts.map ( item => <Product Products={item}/>)
return(

    <div>
       {productComponenets} 
    </div>
    )   
}

export default App
```

---

```
import React from 'react'

function Product (props) {

return (
    <div>
        <h3>{props.product.name}</h3>
        <h6>{props.product.price.toLocaleString("en-Us", {style: "currency", currency: "USD"})}</h6>
        <p>{props.product.description}</p>

    </div>
)
}

export default Product
```

---

```
const products = [

{
    id:"1",
    name:"Pencil",
    price:1,
    description:"Pencil Description Goes Here Pencil Description Goes Here Pencil Description Goes Here"
},

{
    id:"2",
    name:"Housing",
    price:0,
    description:"Housing Description Goes Here Housing Description Goes Here Housing Description Goes Here"
},

{
    id:"3",
    name:"Computer Rental",
    price:300,
    description:"Computer Rental Description Goes Here Computer Rental Description Goes Here Computer Rental Description Goes Here"
},

{
    id:"4",
    name:"coffe",
    price:2,
    description:"coffe Description Goes Here coffe Description Goes Here coffe Description Goes Here"
},

{
    id:"5",
    name:"Snacks",
    price:0,
    description:"Snacks Description Goes Here Snacks Description Goes Here Snacks Description Goes Here"
},

{
    id:"6",
    name:"Rubber Duckies",
    price:3.5,
    description:"Rubber Duckies Description Goes Here Rubber Duckies Description Goes Here Rubber Duckies Description Goes Here"
}
]
export default products
```

Comment: Can you please tell us which file is which?

Comment: because it's Products the prop "<Product Products={item}/>" so in product props.products.name ... also use lowercase for component attrs : <Product products={item}/>

Comment: It should be `{props.Products.name}` and so on...

Comment: import React from 'react'

function Product (props) {

return (
    <div>
        <h3>{props.product.name}</h3>
        <h6>{props.product.price.toLocaleString("en-Us", {style: "currency", currency: "USD"})}</h6>
        <p>{props.product.description}</p>

    </div>
)
}

export default Product

Comment: when i use lowercase it's not return anything on blink page and this in the console index.js:1 Warning: The tag <product> is unrecognized in this browser. If you meant to render a React component, start its name with an uppercase letter.
    in product (at App.js:7)
    in div (at App.js:10)
    in App (at src/index.js:9)

Comment: @ravibagul91 no it's not working like that aswell look at down some 1 answer it and it's work but i cant understand why it's not working with props

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use like this

```
const productComponenets = vschoolProducts.map ( item => <Product product={item}/>)

function Product ({product}) {
  return (
      <div>
          <h3>{product.name}</h3>
          <h6>{product.price.toLocaleString("en-Us", {style: "currency", currency: "USD"})}</h6>
          <p>{product.description}</p>
      </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: thank you it's work but i have a question why it was'nt working with props ?

Comment: You were using props named `props.product` in Product component. But Why did you send props as Products={item}?

Comment: ummm i dont know i just did what he did in course and it's worked for him but i dont know about mine srsly i cant understand props too much the only thing i know about props that can transfar data from component to anyothe copmonent

Comment: ah about that Products={item}? i was trying to fix it by calling the function it didnt fix so i forget to write product={item} again

Comment: first, I think you need to understand about JSX. https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized

Comment: thank you i will and i re write it with props and it's working thank you alot for the help <3

Answer (score 0):

The simple reason is you have misspelled the word while calling in Product.js

In App.js you have defined it as "Products" while in Product.js you are calling it as "product".

React JS is extremely type sensitive.

I remember I was working and I imported everything but still it was showing react is not defined. It took me half an hour to realise I have imported

"`r`eact" instead of "`R`eact" . The "R" was in lowercase. So please do check it out while typing.

[See this image for proof of perfect execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9qwH.png)